# Leer caracteres de una cadena de texto antes de un espacio con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito hacer lo siguiente, y no encuentro una forma adecuada para hacerlo...

Este es el código de una función, que mete dos tabulados (dos espacios con \t) al encontrar el primer espacio dentro de la variable 'customText'.

```
function generatePageLinks(text, isChapter, pageId) {

        //Variable auxiliar que captura el texto de la página de 'text'.

        var aux = text;
        var customText = aux.replace(" ", "\t\t");


        var $element = $(document.createElement('td'));
        var $link = $('<a class="hier-link"></a>').attr('href', '#').attr('data-page-id', pageId).text(customText);

        $element.append('<div class="text-wrapper">');
        $element.append($('<pre class="hier-move">').html(isChapter ? customText : $link));
        return $element;

    }
```

Necesito mejorar ésta función, para que aplique dos tabulados cuando haya 2 caracteres antes del espacio, y un único tabulado en caso de que haya 3 caracteres antes de espacio.

Es viable? Mil gracias de ante mano!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utiliza `indexOf`... Sirve para obtener la primera ubicación de la cadena dada.

Ejemplo

```
if (aux.indexOf(' ') == 2) {
  // hay dos caracteres antes del primer espacio 
  var customText = aux.replace(" ", "\t\t"); // se remplaza por 2 tabs
} else if (aux.indexOf(' ') == 3) {
  // hay 3
  var customText = aux.replace(" ", "\t"); // se reeplaza por 1 tab
} else {
   // otro caso
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Perfecto, esta es la que ha dado en el clavo. Muchas gracias compañero!.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar expresiones regulares:

```
texto = texto.replace(/([^\s]{2})\s/, "$1\t\t");
texto = texto.replace(/([^\s]{3})\s/, "$1\t");
```

La primera línea reemplaza dos caracteres seguidos de un espacio por esos dos caracteres seguidos de dos tabuladores.

La segunda línea reemplaza tres caracteres seguidos de un espacio por esos tres caracteres seguidos de un solo tabulador.

#### Detalle de la expresión regular

- `[^\s]` esto significa: cualquier caracter que no sea un espacio
- `[^\s]{2}` esto significa: cualquier caracter que no sea un espacio, repetido 2 veces

Si agrupamos algo con paréntesis, como he hecho con `([^\s]{2})`, eso nos permite utilizarlo luego al reemplazar. Es decir, que se guarda esa coincidencia para usarla después, por medio de `$1`.
Si hubiese varios grupos, usaríamos `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

De forma visual:
[image: regexper]

Por tanto, volviendo al replace, estamos buscando 2 caracteres que no sean espacios (los guardamos en `$1`), seguidos de un espacio, y los reemplazamos por `$1` seguido de dos tabuladores.
Y en la segunda línea, en vez de 2 caracteres son 3, y en vez de 2 tabuladores, es uno.

Puede ser complicado si no conoces las expresiones regulares, pero en dos líneas ya tienes lo que buscabas.

La expresión regular siempre va a ser más rápida que recorrer todos los caracteres y buscando a mano. Además es extremadamente potente. Con apenas unos cambios puedes por ejemplo aplicar el reemplazo a todo el texto, no solo a la primera aparición, o lo que se te ocurra.

Comment: Tal como le comenté al otro compañero, estudiaré como funcionan ya que en el curso superior y hasta ahora, no se había dado el caso para utilizarlo. Muchas gracias!.

Answer (score 2):

ésta es una buena ocasión para usar **expresiones regulares**, busca algún tutorial de *RegExpr* y juega un poco con alguno de los sites de pruebas de RegEx como por ejemplo https://regex101.com/#javascript

una vez te hayas familiarizado un poco con estos juguetes, prueba las siguientes expresiones regulares contra tus cadenas de pruebas

este expresión `^(\S{2})\s` empareja cuando hay exactamente dos caracteres al inicio de la cadena que no son espacios a los que sigue un espacio en blanco y captura los dos caracteres.

esta otra `^(\S{3})\s` lo hace cuando hay exactamente tres caracteres al inicio de la cadena que no son espacios a los que sigue un espacio en blanco.

Usar estas expresiones regulares en javascript para reemplazar el espacio por tabuladores, es muy fácil.

Simplemente usa `string.replace()` con ellas como primer parámetro, y utilizando el texto capturado en la cadena.

```
text.replace(/^(\S{2})\s/, "$1\t\t");
```

o

```
text.replace(/^(\S{3})\s/, "$1\t");
```

Comment: Si había leído algo al buscar ejemplos en Google, tomo nota y trataré de darle sentido y aprender cuándo deben o pueden usarse, muchas gracias!.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar javascript de esta manera:

var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substr(0, 2);

Resultado

```
He
```

O puedes hacer esto también:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

Resultado

```
res[0] = Hello
res[1] = world!
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Si, gracias, éste método lo conocía pero para hacer una validación según la condición, no podría usarlo no? Ej. if (texto tiene 2 caracteres antes del espacio) { hacer....} else if  (si tiene 3...) se puede aplicar tu ejemplo a ésta necesidad?.

Comment: si, lo podrias hacer asi: `numeroEspaciosBlanco = res.length;` y con un if else del numro de espacios

Answer (score 0):

Según como lo planteas no se si solo quieres remplazar la primera aparición de los espacios o todas las veces que aparezcan.

Si es solo la primera lo aconsejable sería hacer una búsqueda con indexOf.

Sin embargo creo que te refieres a sustituir todos los triple espacios por un tabulador, y los dobles por 2 tabuladores. En ese caso lo correcto sería:

```
var customText = text.replace(/^[ ]{3}/, "\t")
                     .replace(/^[ ]{2}/, "\t\t");
```

Primero: los corchetes no son estrictamente necesarios, pero los coloco para deja explícitamente claro que se remplazan espacios en blanco normales. No es correcto usar el "\s" ya que este operador toma en cuenta también tabuladores y saltos de linea.

Segundo: Se realiza el de 3 espacios primero, ya que el caso de 2 es similar pero menor y este puede afectar al otro.

```
"   " cambiaría por "\t\t " y ya el cambio de 3 no tendría efecto.
```

Comment: creo que tu respuesta no responde al requerimiento del OP. No pretende cambiar los dos o tres caracteres iniciales, sino el espacio que sigue a dichos caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente ejemplo muestro la manera correcta de hacerlo, para ello se debe utilizar la expresión `/\s+/` para resolver el problema ya que un **tab** cuenta como **espacio** por tal motivo pudiera darse el caso donde:

1. hay un **espacio** o **tab** y debe ser reemplazado por 2 **tabs** (en el caso donde hay 2 caracteres al principio).
2. hay 2 **espacio** o **tabs** y deben ser reemplazados por 1 **tab** (en el caso donde hay 3 caracteres al principio (es por esto que considero colocar el signo + en la expresión, partiendo del caso donde debemos contar el primer espacio y todos los que le sigan para obtener el resultado deseado).

En el siguiente ejemplo muestro los caso planteados conjuntamente con las diferentes expresiones dadas en otras respuesta de esta pregunta:

```js
var exp = [ /[ ]/, /\s/, /\s+/ ];
for (i in exp) {
 console.log("aplicando exp["+exp[i]+"]:"); 
 console.log("En texto con 1 espacio"); 
 console.log(addTabs(exp[i], "ab cdef"));
 console.log(addTabs(exp[i], "abc def"));
 console.log("En texto con 2 espacio"); 
 console.log(addTabs(exp[i], "ab  cdef"));
 console.log(addTabs(exp[i], "abc  def"));
 console.log("En texto con espacios+tab"); 
 console.log(addTabs(exp[i], "ab \t cdef"));
 console.log(addTabs(exp[i], "abc \t def"));
}

function addTabs(exp, text) {
 text = text.replace(exp, function (str, i, text) {
  if(i == 2){
   return "\t\t";
  } else if(i == 3){
   return "\t";
  } else {
   return str;
  }
 });
 return text;
};
```

Como verán donde aplicamos la expresión **/\s+/** los 3 ejemplos dan el mismo resultado, sin embargo saquen Uds. sus propias conclusiones de cual debe ser la manera correcta, Saludos!! ;))...